# What is happening in Console.Write() when i put int array as parameter?

Tags: arrays, cil, console.writeline

Question like in title. What is exactly happening when Write method is invoked? If I have code like this:

```
int [] t = new int[]{2,1};
Console.Write(t);
```

is there any posibility that without changing Write method parameter (without adding [0]) number 2 will be displayed? (first element of array) Will this code give the same result in different .NET framework versions?

[image: Method using Console.WriteLine in C# and ildasm]

Why this method doesn't write type of y? (System.Int32[])

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(object)` -> `object.ToString()`

Comment: ok, I know that. Now is it possible that t.ToString() is not giving "System.Int32[]" but "2"? Maby ToString() works differnet with other .NET framework version?

Answer (score 2):

No that is not really possible since you would have to redefine the `toString()` method of Int32[].

Console.Write(t) is simply `Console.Write(t.toString())` and `t.toString()` is `Int32[].toString()`.

The behavior of `Int32[].toString()` is to simply return the type, in this case  `System.Int32[]`.

So to answer your question, no you cannot make the `Int32[].toString()` return the `toString()` of the first index.

Comment: Do keep in mind the overloads, though. `Console.Write(charArray)`, where `charArray` is of type `char[]` would "have more meaningful output".